# ECM long-run elasticity with one I(2) variable

Tags: time-series, unit-root, 2sls, elasticity, ecm

I am estimating a 2SLS using a time series simultaneous equation ECM. The purpose is to estimate the price elasticity of electricity demand. Assume that both price and demand are I(1) variables, becoming I(0) after differencing once. The main equation is consumption:

[image: Formula]

The price is estimated using instruments:

[image: Formula]
[image: Formula]

Rewriting the consumption function, the **long run relationship** between quantity and price is given by the fraction coefficient on [image] inside the bracket:

[image]

Now, I have come to realize that [image] is in fact an **I(2)** integrated variable, and is not stationary after being differenced once. [image] is still I(1). My question is how this ECM changes to accommodate a second differencing of [image]. And importantly, what happens to the long run relationship between [image] and [image]?

Edit:
A graph of [image] and [image]
[image]

Comment: $\ln(Q_t)$ being I(2) means $\Delta\ln(Q_t):=\ln(Q_t)-\ln(Q_{t-1})$ has a unit root, i.e. *changes* in $\ln(Q_t)$ are highly persistent. Is that plausible? Might it be that $\ln(Q_t)$ is merely I(1) but there are some nuisance artifacts in the data that make this hard to see? It is an open question, I am not claiming $\ln(Q_t)$ *has* to be I(1). Perhaps economic theory can guide you as to what order of integration $\ln(Q_t)$ should have.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you. It's definitely a possibility, as you suggest, that ln(Qt) is in fact an I(1). I started from this assumption as it seems most reasonable. It's the difficulty in resolving autocorrelated residuals and the ADF test that has lead me to think it might be I(2).

Comment: Could you include a plot of the $\Delta\ln(Q_t)$ series? Additionally, $\ln(Q_t)$ would also be interesting to see.

Comment: @RichardHardy I've edited the post with a data plot of ln(Q_t) and Dln(Q_t).

Comment: OK, so $\ln(Q_t)$ seems to be highly seasonal. It is not obvious at all that it contains even a single unit root. Try adjusting for seasonality and then examine the adjusted series for possible presence of a unit root. (Though with only 3 years of data, adjusting for seasonality will be a challenge.)